how to script python to get the index menu geometry node modifier?
i want to get  the 'Gold' value material in script python to use like this bpy.data.materials['Gold']


This question is similar to: Set group input to attribute in geometry nodes python without ops. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
